# Onchange function Javascript stops working after ACF is upgraded on wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

After I have upgraded ACF plugin, My onchange function JS file is not working anymore on wordpress function.php. I don't know what happened to it.
Here is my code. Could you please enlighten me?

**irevent_script.JS**

```
(function($) { 

     $('#acf-field-acf_event_type').on('change', function () {
     var selectVal = $("#acf-field-acf_event_type option:selected").val();

     if(selectVal=="Others") { 
        $("#title").val("");
     } else {
        $("#title").val(selectVal);
     }
});  
})( jQuery ); 



In function.php


function irevent_script( $hook_suffix ){
        $cpt = 'irevent';

        if( in_array($hook_suffix, array('post.php', 'post-new.php') ) ){
            $screen = get_current_screen();

            if( is_object( $screen ) && $cpt == $screen->post_type ){
                //wp_enqueue_script( 'tinymce_js', includes_url( 'js/tinymce/' ) . 'wp-tinymce.php', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );

                wp_enqueue_script('irevent_js_script', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/irevent_script.js', array('jquery'), '4.7.5', true);

            }
        }
    }

    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'irevent_script');
```

Comment: I don't know if this will help. But it would be best to have the full url on your wp_enque linking to your script

Comment: @ScottChambers Thank you for your help. I have noticed that the event type ID has been changed after ACF upgraded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that event type ID has been changed after ACF upgraded.So, I had to change event type ID in javascript as well. Now, it works.